# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have 2 DropDownList (entity and process), the second one is alimented according to the selected value on the first list through OnSelectedIndexChanged event.
The problem is, when I change the selection on the process DDL, the OnSelectedIndexChanged of the entity DDL is fired.

```
                    <asp:GridView runat="server"
                        ID="pEntityProcess_GridView"
                        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="200" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="600px"
                        DataKeyNames="EntityProcessID"
                        OnRowDataBound="pEntityProcess_GridView_RowDataBound"
                        OnRowEditing="pEntityProcess_GridView_RowEditing"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="pEntityProcess_GridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                        OnRowUpdating="pEntityProcess_GridView_RowUpdating"
                        OnRowDeleting="pEntityProcess_GridView_RowDeleting"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="pEntityProcess_GridView_PageIndexChanging"
                        FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entités" InsertVisible="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="pEntityProcess_EntityId_lbl" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EntityId") %>' />
                                    <asp:Label ID="pEntityProcess_EntityName_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EntityName") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="pEntityProcess_NewEntityList" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="pEntityProcess_NewEntityList_SelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="false"  />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Process" InsertVisible="False" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="pEntityProcess_ProcessList" runat="server" Width="100%" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="pEntityProcess_ProcessName_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProcessName") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="pEntityProcess_NewProcessList" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="pEntityProcess_NewProcessList_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Have I Forget something ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could be something with AutoPostBack? I remember it being a HUGE pain.

Comment: Do you need the event OnSelectedIndexChanged in the second dropdownlist ? I understood that the second one is based on the first, right ?

Comment: Did you wrap the databinding of the GridView inside an `IsPostBack` check? And what about the databinding of the DDL's?

Comment: I Added "pEntityProcess_NewProcessList_SelectedIndexChanged" event just to test if it is fired but I don't need it. I don't need the isAutoPostBack test, the DDL lists must be load for every change, otherwise it will be empty